No DOM update with HTMX and GoLang
I'm trying to learn HTMX with Go and GoFiber.
Here is my HTML page :
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@2.0.0" integrity="sha384-wS5l5IKJBvK6sPTKa2WZ1js3d947pvWXbPJ1OmWfEuxLgeHcEbjUUA5i9V5ZkpCw" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<main>
    <div class="grid h-screen place-items-center">
        <div class="flex flex-col items-center space-y-4">
            <h1 class="text-5xl font-bold mb-16">Connexion</h1>
            <form hx-post="/auth" hx-target="#error-message" hx-swap="innerHTML" class="flex flex-col items-center space-y-4">
                <input
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Mot de passe"
                    class="input input-bordered input-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                    id="password"
                    name="password"
                />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Connexion</button>
            </form>
            <div id="error-message" class="text-red-500"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

and here is the /auth route of my API in GoFiber
func Auth(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    // get the password on the body
    clientPassword := c.FormValue("password")

    // check if the password is correct
    password, err := database.GetPassword()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to get the password: %v", err)
        return c.Status(fiber.StatusInternalServerError).SendString("Internal Server Error : cannot get the password in db")
    }

    if clientPassword != password {
        log.Println("Incorrect password")
        return c.Status(fiber.StatusUnauthorized).SendString("<p class='text-red-500'>Incorrect password. Please try again.</p>")
    }

    log.Println("Correct password")

    // redirect the client on the home page
    return c.Redirect("/videos")
}


My problem is that when I send an incorrect password, the API correctly receives the request and my browser correctly receives the response with a status code of 401 and the HTML string. However, the message sent by the API does not appear in the error-message div. Why didn't it work, and how can I fix this?
(I tried swapping the outerHTML, targeting a class insted of an id but nothing seem to work.)

The target is replaced when your request is successful. In this case you have an error code. You need to use another htmx extension for error cases. More info here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73615279/6031948

HTMX by default only processes successful requests. If you want to handle 401 responses, you have two basic choices. I would say up front that I am not a fan of using 401 for this purpose, I would use 422 instead which is "unprocessable entity". It is a better fit for what is essentially a validation type of error from the perspective of a login form. Your mileage may vary.
Option 1: Use an extension library
https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx-extensions/blob/main/src/response-targets/README.md
If you use it, be aware that it is not enough to include the script in your page. You also need to activate it using hx-ext : https://htmx.org/docs/#extensions
Example setup:
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx-ext-response-targets@2.0.0/response-targets.js"></script>
<body hx-ext="response-targets">

<form hx-post="/auth" hx-target-422="#error-message"

Option 2: Tell HTMX that it should process specific status codes
Adding a whole different extension library just to get one task done might seem overkill; I wouldn't want to riddle my front end with large amounts of status-code specific target directives. Fortunately HTMX is quite configurable. You can tell it that you do want to "swap" on specific response codes. https://htmx.org/docs/#requests
Example:
document.body.addEventListener('htmx:beforeSwap', function(evt) {
  if(evt.detail.xhr.status == 422) {
    evt.detail.shouldSwap = true;
    evt.detail.isError = false;
  }
});

Rinse and repeat for any other error status codes you would want to handle in your front-end. Just keep in mind that if you start to put a long list of response codes here... you may want to rethink if you actually need HTMX for your use case.
